# overflow:hidden on a div not working properly - iOS

Tags: ios, css, overflow

As of now I'm running into an issue when it comes to testing a website on iOS devices. It seems a **DIV** element does not carry its **overflow:hidden** property well. Or at all, really.

This is what the site's layout should be (with the overflow-setting working):

[image: overflow:hidden working as it should]

This is what the layout is like on an iOS device:

[image: overflow:hidden not working is it should]

I've tried many things, such as editing the **body** and **html** css overflow and/or position properties, adding a wrapper around the **body** tag and many more 'mainstream' solutions I came across while googling. None worked, sadly.

The CSS for the item not properly working on iOS is this:

```
width: 94.4%;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

How'd I know (or at least think) it's the overflow? As soon as I turn it off in the browser through inspecting the element, the issue happens.

Is there anybody who can give me some insight into the issue?
If you need any more information, I'd be happy to provide.

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align:top` to your CSS. This might fix it.

Comment: Need all your HTML and CSS, its impossible to work out whats going on without it

Comment: @JamesKing The amount of HTML and CSS this project has is enormous:  I can assure you it wouldn't fit in a comment :)

Comment: @Demnogonis I'll try that out as soon as I get to the office. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Demnogonis This fixed it. I'll add it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Demnogonis suggested in a comment to my original post, I added

```
vertical-align: top
```

And now the layout is fixed on iOS devices.